# Calculating ERA5 2018 monthly 2mt temperature anomalies in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, climate, spatial-analysis

I am trying to calculate in Google Earth Engine using ERA5 the **monthly 2mt temperature anomalies from January to December 2018** compared to the long-term **reference period** of 1981-2010. In other words, I would like to compare the temp anomaly of January 2018 with January of the long-term period. Finally, I would like to create a and **create a time-lapse video** from **January to December 2018**.
As a starting point, I am using the "Iterating over an ImageCollection" code example, but I don't get it working properly with the ERA5 data.

[link to the code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8111033c27a6df79ea55367450045648) and the code.

```
// Load era5
var era5_2mt = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY')
               .select('mean_2m_air_temperature')
               .map(function (image){
                return image.clip(geometry);
  });
print(era5_2mt);

// Define reference conditions from the first 30 years of data.
var eraref = era5_2mt.filterDate('1980-01-01', '2010-12-31')
  // Sort chronologically in descending order.
.sort('system:time_start', false);

// Compute the mean of the first 30 years.
var mean = eraref.mean();

// Compute anomalies by subtracting the 1980-2010 mean from each image 
in a
// collection of 2018 images. Copy the date metadata over to the
// computed anomaly images in the new collection.
var series = era5_2mt.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12- 
31').map(function(image) {
    return image.subtract(mean).set('system:time_start', 
image.get('system:time_start'));
});
var series2 = series.map(function(img){
    return img.clip(geometry);
});


// Display cumulative anomalies.
Map.setCenter(-4.12, 39.834, 5);
Map.addLayer(series.sum(),
    {min: -50, max: 50, palette: ['blue','white','red']}, 'Temp 2mt 
anomaly');

// Get the timestamp from the most recent image in the reference 
collection.
var time0 = eraref.first().get('system:time_start');

// Use imageCollection.iterate() to make a collection of cumulative 
anomaly over time.
// The initial value for iterate() is a list of anomaly images already 
processed.
// The first anomaly image in the list is just 0, with the time0 
timestamp.
var first = ee.List([
// Rename the first band 'temp'.
  ee.Image(0).set('system:time_start', time0).select([0], ['temp'])
]);

// This is a function to pass to Iterate().
// As anomaly images are computed, add them to the list.
var accumulate = function(image, list) {
 // Get the latest cumulative anomaly image from the end of the list 
with
  // get(-1).  Since the type of the list argument to the function is 
unknown,
  // it needs to be cast to a List.  Since the return type of get() is 
unknown,
  // cast it to Image.
  var previous = ee.Image(ee.List(list).get(-1));
  // Add the current anomaly to make a new cumulative anomaly image.
  var added = image.add(previous)
    // Propagate metadata to the new image.
    .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
  // Return the list with the cumulative anomaly inserted.
  return ee.List(list).add(added);
};

// Create an ImageCollection of cumulative anomaly images by 
iterating.
// Since the return type of iterate is unknown, it needs to be cast to 
a List.
var cumulative = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(series.iterate(accumulate, 
first)));

// Predefine the chart titles.
var title = {
  title: 'Cumulative Temp anomaly over time',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Cumulative Temp anomaly'},
};

// Chart some interesting locations.
//var pt1 = ee.Geometry.Point(-8.669, 41.187);
//print('Porto:',
//Chart.image.series(cumulative, pt1, ee.Reducer.first(), 
500).setOptions(title));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in the start date for computing reference conditions from the first 30 years of data (it computes wrong means). In spite of [Dataset Availability](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ECMWF_ERA5_MONTHLY) of **ERA5 Monthly** aggregates is 1979-01-01 to present, your script run without any error if your reference conditions are changed for 25 years of data or less (e.g. between '1986-01-01' and '2010-12-31').

Your modified code can be ran [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/82f678bf97ecc0caf1e1fb104fca6e80).

After running it, result is observed in following image. It worked!

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that. Do you have any idea how I could estimate the Monthly Anomaly? i.e. my output will be 12 images (January to Decembre) showing the anomaly compared to each month of the reference period. Does it make sense?